# How to iterate through all tags of a website in Python with Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, loops, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm a newbie in this sector. Here is the website I need to crawling "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1430669.html" and here is it source code "view-source:[http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1430669.html"](http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1430669.html%22)
It's a simple website for practice. The HTML code look something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to the comments assignment from www.py4e.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This file contains the actual data for your assignment - good luck!</h1>

<table border="2">
<tr>
<td>Name</td><td>Comments</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Melodie</td><td><span class="comments">100</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Machaela</td><td><span class="comments">100</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>Rhoan</td><td><span class="comments">99</span></td></tr>
```

I need to get the number between comments and span (100,100,99)
Below is my code:

```
html=urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1430669.html').read()

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

tag=soup.span

print(tag) #<span class="comments">100</span>
print(tag.string) #100
```

I got the number 100 but only the first one, now I want to get all of them by iterating through a list or sth like that. What is the method to do this with beautifulsoup?

Comment: You likely want to check out `find_all()` and iterate over the results. Note that `span` is rather generic and you likely want to search for a more specific set of span tags like maybe those inside td tags with a class of "comments".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1430669.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all("span")
for i in tags:
  print(i.string)
```

You can use find_all() function and then iterate it to get the numbers.

If you want names also you can use python dictionary :

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1430669.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all("span")
comments = {}
for index, tag in enumerate(tags):
  commentorName = tag.find_previous('tr').text
  commentorComments = tag.string
  comments[commentorName] = commentorComments
print(comments)
```

This will give you the output as :

```
{'Melodie100': '100', 'Machaela100': '100', 'Rhoan99': '99', 'Murrough96': '96', 'Lilygrace93': '93', 'Ellenor93': '93', 'Verity89': '89', 'Karlie88': '88', 'Berlin85': '85', 'Skylar84': '84', 'Benny84': '84', 'Crispin81': '81', 'Asya79': '79', 'Kadi76': '76', 'Dua74': '74', 'Stephany73': '73', 'Eila71': '71', 'Jennah70': '70', 'Eduardo67': '67', 'Shannan61': '61', 'Chymari60': '60', 'Inez60': '60', 'Charlene59': '59', 'Rosalin54': '54', 'James53': '53', 'Rhy53': '53', 'Zein52': '52', 'Ayren50': '50', 'Marissa46': '46', 'Mcbride46': '46', 'Ruben45': '45', 'Mikee41': '41', 'Carmel38': '38', 'Idahosa37': '37', 'Brooklin37': '37', 'Betsy36': '36', 'Kayah34': '34', 'Szymon26': '26', 'Tea24': '24', 'Queenie24': '24', 'Nima23': '23', 'Eassan23': '23', 'Haleema21': '21', 'Rahma17': '17', 'Rob17': '17', 'Roma16': '16', 'Jeffrey14': '14', 'Yorgos12': '12', 'Denon11': '11', 'Jasmina7': '7'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_1430669.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = []

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    row = [td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    data.append(row[1])     # or data.append(row) for both
    
print(data)
```

Giving you `data` holding a list containing just the one column:

```
['Comments', '100', '100', '99', '96', '93', '93', '89', '88', '85', '84', '84', '81', '79', '76', '74', '73', '71', '70', '67', '61', '60', '60', '59', '54', '53', '53', '52', '50', '46', '46', '45', '41', '38', '37', '37', '36', '34', '26', '24', '24', '23', '23', '21', '17', '17', '16', '14', '12', '11', '7']
```

First locate all of the table `<tr>` rows. Then extract all of the `<td>` values for each row. As you only want the second one, append `row[1]` to a `data` list holding your values.

You can skip the first one if needed with `data[1:]`.

This approach would let you also save the name at the same time by appending the whole of `row`. e.g. use `data.append(row)` instead...

You could then display the entries using:

```py
for name, comment in data[1:]:
    print(name, comment)
```

Giving output starting:

```
Melodie 100
Machaela 100
Rhoan 99
Murrough 96
Lilygrace 93
Ellenor 93
Verity 89
Karlie 88
```

Comment: Thank you. Still, I found a simple method "for i in soup.find_all('span'): print(i.string)". I'm trying to get the name but still stuck.

Comment: My approach gets both as pairs if you append the whole row, which would also work for any number of columns without change